# How can I reference dynamic keys on an object in jq?

Tags: json, object, key, jq, query-by-example

I'm trying to define some custom filter functions and one thing I need to be able to do is pass a list of strings to a filter and get the corresponding values of the input object. For example:

`jq -n '{name: "Chris", age: 25, city: "Chicago"} | myFilter(["name", "age"])'`

should return:

`{"name": "Chris", "age": 25}`.

I know I can use `.[some_string]` to dynamically get a value on an object for a specific string key, but I don't know how to utilize this for multiple string keys. I think the problem I'm running into is that jq by default iterates over *objects* streamed into a filter, but doesn't give a way to iterate over an argument to that filter, even if I use `def myFilter($var)` syntax that the manual recommends for *value-argument behavior*.

Answer (score 1):

You could easily define your `myFilter` using `reduce`:

```
def myFilter($keys):
  . as $in
  | reduce $keys[] as $k (null; . + {($k): $in[$k]} );
```

More interestingly, if you're willing to modify your "Query By Example" requirements slightly, you can simply specify the keys of interest in braces, as illustrated by this example:

```
jq -n '{name: "Chris", age: 25, city: "Chicago"} | {name, age}'
```

If any of the keys cannot be specified in this abbreviated format, simply double-quote them.